# How to prevent android time picker input invalid value

Tags: android, datetimepicker, timepicker, android-timepicker

in my android app i'm using timepicker, in which timepicker spinner mode allow me to input invalid input like displaying in below image, i want to give error when user gives invalid input anyone can help me to solve this problem.

[image]

Layout xml added below

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_double"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOk"
            android:text="OK"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginRight="0.5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are you using custom dailog or default timpicker dailog?

Comment: @haresh i'm using custom dialog. layout xml added you can see

Comment: include your code inside activity